# How to cache composer packges in Jenkins

Tags: php, laravel, docker, jenkins, composer-php

I've got a Laravel project and simple pipeline in Jenkins which build Docker image from Dockerfile, pull code in it and execute `composer install`. Everything working fine so far, but installing composer packages takes a lot of time (like 6-7 minutes). I've tried to persist vendor directory somewhere, create symlink to it or something but nothing worked so far. I wonder if there is some better more official way to handle that? Anyone has some idea or experience in it? Or maybe some different CI tool?

Comment: Where composer's packages located? In the internet? Or you have local repository?

Comment: Also you can mount composers folder into host

Comment: Packages are downloaded from internet right now. I've been thinking about mounting vendor folder but it is located in the same directory where I checkout code from GitHub and I don't know if it won't interference.

Comment: I've tried to mount vendor like this:
```
dockerfile {
      filename 'Dockerfile'
      args '-v $WORKSPACE/../vendor:/app/vendor'
    }
```
Folder on host is created but empty :/

Comment: You can use Sonatype nexus to store and proxy your composer libs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I ended up with two solutions:

1. I mounted composer cache directory to some directory in host to speed up composer packages installing:

```
dockerfile {
  filename 'Dockerfile'
  args '-v $HOME/composer_cache:/.composer/cache'
}
```

2. There is (not so obvious, because Jenkins panel is little messy) option to disable workspace clean up before/after code checkout. One can delete those steps in pipeline configuration under "Branch Sources" section (with red X above those "Behaviours").

Comment: You're welcome to mark your answer as accepted if you feel that it answers you question. :)